# Ignore special characters when fetching data from Oracle database in dot net core

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-core

**Update**
It turned out to be an issue with the unofficial Oracle Data Provider.
I just started using [this recently released official beta](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core) and this issue is gone.

I've a dot net core project and I am using [this](https://github.com/ericmend/oracleClientCore-2.0) to fetch data from a Oracle Database. This works for most of the data but sometimes I get an exception.

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
  OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(selectStatement, connection);
  command.Connection.Open();

  using (OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(command))
  {
    da.Fill(dataTable); // line throws exception shown below
    command.Connection.Close();
    da.Dispose();
  }
}
```

When I exported the data as csv using a SQL client, there seems to be some special character in a column causing this.

When I open it on Notepad, I see an extra space on line 2.
"TEST"
"TEST "

But when I open it on Submlime I see [this special character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHo0f.jpg).

How do I ignore such characters and continue to fetch data?

Here is the exception and stack trace:
**"Index and length must refer to a location within the string.\r\nParameter name: length"**

```
at System.Text.StringBuilder.ToString(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)\r\n   
at System.Data.OracleClient.Oci.OciDefineHandle.GetValue(IFormatProvider formatProvider, OracleConnection conn)\r\n   
at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataReader.GetValues(Object[] values)\r\n   
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DataReaderContainer.CommonLanguageSubsetDataReader.GetValues(Object[] values)\r\n   
at System.Data.ProviderBase.SchemaMapping.LoadDataRow()\r\n   
at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillLoadDataRow(SchemaMapping mapping)\r\n   
at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)\r\n   
at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)\r\n   
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)\r\n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your `SELECT` statement, you may be able to use a regular expression to replace all "special characters". This might depend on what you want to replace them with! If they're only occurring at the end of values then you'll want something like this:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(mycolumn, '[^[:print:]]+$', '')
```

This will replace all of the non-printable chararacters at the end of the value with nothing. If you have non-printable characters in the middle of strings as well, you might want to replace them with spaces or with nothing at all, as above:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(mycolumn, '[^[:print:]]+', '')
```

Another possibility is that this is being caused by the Oracle client, or that it is being written to the CSV file by the export functionality.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot David, it turned out to be an issue with the package/client I was using.